# IDA Pro - Remote debugging suse enterpris server 10 (glibc2_10 required)

Tags: ida, debugging, debuggers

I have a Suse enterprise server 10 on VMWare. I want to remote debug an application in this VM using IDA pro, I already tried these:

1. Copied linux_server form IDApro into this VM and tried to run it, but it gives this error: linux_server : /lib/libc.so.6 : version 'GLIBC_2.7' not foundn (required by ./linux_server)
2. Downloaded and extracted glibc2.7 near linux_server and modified Library search path (environment value) and then tried to run linux_server, but it failed with another error.

I think the problem is that linux_server has been compiled using newer versions of glibc, but that version of suse is using older versions.
so I think the question is: How can I remote debug an application in old-linux machines? Is there exists an older version of debugger that runs is such scenarios?

Comment: "it failed with another error." Please describe the error.

Comment: And as for your actual task, have your tried just using gdb, either locally or with its remote capability?

Comment: Also, what version of glibc is available on SUSE Enterprise server 10? You have a good question; you just need to provide us some details. Like Chris Stratton said above, you may be able to just set up gdbserver and connect to it using IDA Pro.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: 1-if I extract glibc-2.7-12.2mnb1.i586.rpm and put the extracted lib folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, It shows error requiring glibc2.10 and glibc2.11, and if I extract glibc-2.11.1-8.3mnb2.i586.rpm and repeat above steps, it show this error: Error while loading shared libraries: /root/ida68/lib/i686/libc.so.6: ELF file OS ABI invalid        2- I haven't tried gdbserver, I'll try it and let you know the result.

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook : 1- glibc-2.4 is available on this version of suse.   2- I'll try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Are you running 64-bit SUSE? Or 32-bit SUSE? You've made sure that the linux server you're trying to run is the correct architecture?

Comment: @dingo_kinznerhook  "uname -m"prints: "i686", so I think its 32bit.